# What can I pass in the .then() method?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the second point of Sequencing animation - Learn web development | MND (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Sequencing_animations)

and i came out whit a solution that works, but i don't understand why it works.

```
const aliceTumbling = [
    { transform: 'rotate(0) scale(1)' },
    { transform: 'rotate(360deg) scale(0)' }
  ];
  
const aliceTiming = {
    duration: 2000,
    iterations: 1,
    fill: 'forwards'
}

const alice1 = document.querySelector("#alice1");
const alice2 = document.querySelector("#alice2");
const alice3 = document.querySelector("#alice3");


function sinc_animation() {
  const one = alice1.animate(aliceTumbling, aliceTiming)
  one.finished.then(() => alice2.animate(aliceTumbling, aliceTiming).finished)
  .then(() => alice3.animate(aliceTumbling, aliceTiming))
};

sinc_animation();
```

here i wanted to animate the third alice when the second one was done, so at first i just put in the first .then((onFulfilled)):

```
alice2.animate(aliceTumbling, aliceTiming)
```

But the third one started right after the second one started because the .then((onFulfilled)) promise was considered fulfilled at the **start** of the animation.

So how come the code above is able to animate alice2 if I'm passing a promise returned by the .animate() object in the .then() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a `Promise` in the fulfillment handler of `.then`, the `Promise` returned by `.then` will be fulfilled only when that returned `Promise` resolves.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> If the handler function:
>
> - returns a value: p gets fulfilled with the returned value as its value.
> - doesn't return anything: p gets fulfilled with undefined as its value.
> - throws an error: p gets rejected with the thrown error as its value.
>   returns an already fulfilled promise: p gets fulfilled with that promise's value as its value.
> - returns an already rejected promise: p gets rejected with that promise's value as its value.
> - returns another pending promise: p is pending and becomes fulfilled/rejected with that promise's value as its value immediately after that promise becomes fulfilled/rejected.

Comment: But how can alice2 start animating if I'm not telling the handler to animate alice2, but I'm just passing his promise?

Comment: @Darius You called `animate`, which starts the animation. It doesn't matter if you access the `finished` property of the return value or not. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate): the "animate() method is a shortcut method which creates a new Animation, applies it to the element, then plays the animation"